# Google Apps Script: delete Row from Sheet if Cell DOES NOT contain Value from Array

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, delete-row

In Google Spreadsheets I have a 'DataSheet'. Cells in Column 'J' contain 'ColumnName' and language codes like "en", "fr", "de" and so on. I'm trying to delete all rows except those with values from the array 'valuesToLeave'.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong here?

```
function deleteRowsLangs() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName('DataSheet');
  var r = s.getRange('J:J');
  var allValues = r.getValues();
  var valuesToLeave = ["en", "fr", "de"];
  for(var i=allValues.length-1;i>=0;i--)
  
  if(allValues[i] != valuesToLeave[0]){
      s.deleteRow(i+1);
      
    } else {
      //doNothing
    } 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function deleteRowsLangs() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('DataSheet');
  const rg = sh.getRange(1,10,sh.getLastRow(),1);
  const vs = rg.getValues().flat();
  const vtl = ["en", "fr", "de"];
  let d = 0;
  vs.forEach((e,i) => {
   if(!~vtl.indexOf(e)){sh.deleteRow(i + 1 - d++)}
  });
}
```